# Meaning of the various symbols in .aspx page of asp.net

Tags: asp.net, symbols

I have come across different symbols in .aspx page of asp.net

```
<%#eval(expr) %> 
<%#bind(expr) %>
<% %>  - for specifying the c# code in aspx page
<%$ %> - for specifying the SQL connection string in <asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is there any underlying logic behind these symbols or is it just syntax which we have to remember blindly? What does <% %> mean in general?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is just syntax.

`<% %>` is simply short for `<script runat="server"> </script>` aka [code render blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z.aspx).

`<%# %>` are [binding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) (plus the above).

`<%= %>` is the above + a `Response.Write()`.

`<%: %>` is the above + a `Response.Write()` wrapped in `Html.Encode` (new in .NET 4.0).

`<%$ %>` is an [ASP.NET expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx), used to bind configuration or resource file data during runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you cite any references on this information?  I have tried to find this in documentation many times, with no results.  Also, what about <%$ %> ?

Comment: @pseudocoder - Follow the links. I don't know about `<%$ %>`.

Comment: I did some digging based of your initial links and I found out that `<%$ %>` is called an [ASP.NET Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx) and allows you to pull values from configuration or resource files.

Comment: <% ... %> is not simply short for <script runat=server>! Such blocks (<% ... %>) contain code that becomes a part of the Render() method, while <script runat=server> blocks contain methods and other class members themselves.

Comment: Another construct is `<%-- .. --%>` for comment blocks (that won't turn up in the resulting HTML).

Comment: I realise this is nearly 5 years later, but might be worth adding to your list the `<%#: %>` notation... which is the HTML encoded version of the binding expression that was [added as part of ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097391)

Answer (score 2):

Remember it.  It's more poorly documented ASP.net syntax to help maintain inconsistencies and fallout from ASP 'classic'  *groans*.  Also don't forget

```
<%=variablename %>
```