# <%: %> Syntax for HTML Encoding in a repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, html-encode

Since .NET 4 its possible to use the <%: %> syntax for HTML Encoding of text.

In a repeater I use the following syntax to display data

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fieldlabel")%>
```

The only way I know of to encode the output in the repeater is by using "Server.HtmlDecode". Is it possible to use the new  <%: %> in a repeater just in combination with databinding so that I can remove the ugly HtlmDecode syntax. Or is an extention method my only option to improved the readability?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of [ASP.NET 4.5 this is possible](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097391) using the new `<%#: %>` notation

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible.  The `<%#` is allowing the evaulation of binding data but it use the basic `<%` block.

The only thing you can do is recreate the `<%:` by wrapping your code in `Html.Encode`.

Eg:

```
<%# Html.Encode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fieldlabel")) %>
```

The `<%:` is a shortcut and I guess not every variation of the use of the blocks has been captured to include a shortbut.  MS probably didn't want to complicate the issue by creating a ton of different symbols to capture the various uses and only support the most common use.

Comment: Please note, as of [.NET 4.5 this is possible](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097391) using the new `<%#: %>` notation

Comment: @freefaller thanks for the update, after almost 5 years I guess they finally addressed the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is no, based on this question.

[Meaning of the various symbols in .aspx page of asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833278/meaning-of-the-various-symbols-in-aspx-page-of-asp-net/5833310#5833310)

Comment: they need a <%!: %> tag... for decoding.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but need to work more:

Please use below syntax

```
<asp:Literal ID="fieldlabel" runat="server" Mode="Encode" Text='<%#Eval("fieldlabel")%>"></asp:Literal>
```