# Using ASPxGridView DataBinding

Tags: html, asp.net, devexpress

In DevExpress AspxGridview control binding

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     // in this event I want to reach LabelText and modify it as "text =Server.HtmlDecode(text);" 
}
```

Bu I can not reach LabelText. I tried to find a solution but never found.

Please help me. I am stuck ....

```
<dx:GridViewDataColumn VisibleIndex="0" Width="100%" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"     CellStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" Caption=" "> <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />     <DataItemTemplate> <table class="table_white"> <tr> <td style="text-align:left">
<asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
</td> </tr> <tr> <td style="text-align:left"> <asp:Label ID="LabelText" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("text") %>'></asp:Label>

</td> </tr> <tr> <td style="text-align:left">
<hr style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC" />
</td> </tr> </table> </DataItemTemplate>
<CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>      </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: you are using dev express grid control isn't it ?

Comment: -Bibhu yes I am using devexpress

Comment: -Bibhu I encode it like = text = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(text);... And used your code but does not decode

Answer (score 1):

You can simple do it in the markup as below:

```
Text='<%# Server.HtmlEncode( (string) Eval( "text" ) ) %>' />
```

Refer:
[How to use HtmlEncode with TemplateFields, Data Binding, and a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512517/how-to-use-htmlencode-with-templatefields-data-binding-and-a-gridview)
[<%: %> Syntax for HTML Encoding in a repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869336/syntax-for-html-encoding-in-a-repeater)
[HtmlEncode and Bind Description](http://forums.asp.net/p/1056231/1504717.aspx)
[ASP.NET "special" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

If you want it to access the label control and then use the grid `HtmlRowCreated` event then you can modify the text.. Refer below link...

[Find controls in a dataitemtemplate of ASPxGridView column](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.in/2011/11/find-controls-in-dataitemtemplate-of.html)
[ASPxGridView - How to find a control in grid DataItemTemplate - using DataBoundEvent event](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q334279)

example

```
Protected Sub ASPxGridView1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ASPxGridView1.DataBound
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        Dim x As Integer = Me.ASPxGridView1.VisibleRowCount - 1
        For y = 0 To x
            Dim ilabel As ASPxLabel = CType(Me.ASPxGridView1.FindRowCellTemplateControl(y, Nothing, "lblCategory"), ASPxLabel)
            If ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(y, "CategoryName").ToString() = "Confections" Then
                ilabel.ClientVisible = False
            End If
        Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: follow the reference link and try to use databound event if you think it will work then..

Comment: I reach elements in ASPxGridView1_HtmlRowPrepared but htmldecode does not run  ==  text = Server.HtmlDecode(text);  no decode

Comment: Outside of gridview I tested it and I use it and it decodes. Bu when I try to decode in gridview it does not decode.... Why ???

Comment: Finally !.. if I use "asp:Label" decodes runs... bu if I use "dx:ASPxLabel" decodes does no run !.... SOLUTION FOUND