# Name for Angle Bracket Percent Sign

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET “special” tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

Is there a proper name for <%...> in ASP.NET, or do people really call it "Angle Bracket Percent"?

Comment: According to PHP, it's *ASP tags*.

Comment: Are they also used in PHP? (I know nothing about PHP)

Comment: I'm going to go with *code block* or *render block*, according to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0111sbh.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Meaning of the Various Symbols in aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833278/meaning-of-the-various-symbols-in-aspx-page-of-asp-net) for more information on this topic.

According to MSDN, they are called *[code render blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)*.

Answer (score 9):

in ASP.NET `<% ... %>` represents server-side code which has been in-lined to an ASPX HTML document. The name would be dependent on which variety.

`<% ... %>` Normal Code block

`<%= ... %>` Serverside code wrapped in `Response.Write()`

`<%# ... %>` Specific to Databinding

`<%-- --%>` Server side comment

`<%$ ... %>` for expression bindings

Comment: Let's not forget <%$ %> for expression bindings!

Comment: And <%: ... %> is the same as <%= ... %>, but the output is HTML encoded and they've also introduced <%#: ... %> for HTML-encoded data-binding in .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 3):

I've always called them code render blocks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In this blog post they're called code nuggets.

[ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Its just a notation for an ASP/ASP.NET inline code block.