# what is the purpose of angle bracket percent in html

Tags: html, user-interface

I just wanted to know what <% these exactly do? %> I've used these for exporting some html tables and data to excel, but i don't really know what it's function is. 
any answers are appreciated.

so like when i use these in below coding, am i actually using asp?

```
<body>
<%
    String exportToExcel = request.getParameter("exportToExcel");
    if (exportToExcel != null && exportToExcel.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) { //application/vnd.ms-excel
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); //application/vnd.opentextformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + "whatever.xls");
    }
%>
```

i got it from http://www.quicklyjava.com/export-web-page-to-word

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this information can be found by a simple search

Comment: do you use any kind of templating engine? this could be anything...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET "special" tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered over here: [Name for Angle Bracket Percent Sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870384/name-for-angle-bracket-percent-sign). Which then links to another answer.

In short, they are code render blocks which execute when the page is rendered. They are expressions as a part of the ASP.net framework, from what I can gather.

More information: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.71).aspx)

EDIT: As others have commented, I found all this from a quick search.