# What does <%# "whatever" %> mean in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax, webforms-view-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning of the various symbols in .aspx page of asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833278/meaning-of-the-various-symbols-in-aspx-page-of-asp-net)

I'm familiar with `<%= "whatever" %>` as a shortcut for `<% Response.Write("whatever"); %>`.

But I've recently come across some code that uses `<%# %>` instead. In this particular codebase, it's only being used inside of an `<asp:Repeater />` but I

What does `<%# %>` do and when can/should it be used?

Comment: It means you're binding some data element.  The repeater probably has a data source which are being repeated inside of your control.

Comment: George, can you elaborate?  My C#/ASP.NET skills are pretty basic.

Comment: Data binding on a repeater control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719636%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @ChrisF, thanks for pointing that one out. I think this question should be closed rather than being deleted, just to have some additional search terms available.

Comment: Marking as duplicate doesn't delete it. It will stay open as a duplicate and alternate search result. There's at least one more I think, but I can't find it because the search for `%>` doesn't work!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **<%# ... %>**
>
> Data-binding expressions are an important set of code delimiters, which are used to create a binding between a server control property and a data source.

More about it here:

[ASP.NET Code Delimiters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)

Comment: Linked page isn't working

Answer (score 2):

Its used in conjunction with Databind.Eval as in <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price") %>

Here is an [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx) page onthe matter

Answer (score 1):

That's how you do "BINDING" you may want to do a google search on asp.net data binding
also to if you are using something like system.web.htmlcontrols this is how you could also get at document variables by name when using javascript.