# Conditional hyperlink is not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, hyperlink, href

I used hyperlinks in menu section in my asp.net application. 
I want to redirect user to the specific page based on the type of user. Here is the code I am using

```
<li>
<a id="store" href= "<%# (Session["Coupon"] == "Active") ? "url1.aspx": "url2.aspx" %>"></a>
</li>
```

If Session["Coupon"] == "Active" then user should redirect to "url1.aspx"
else redirect to "url2.aspx".

Can anyone please help me how to give condition to hyperlink to get redirected?

Comment: What happens at the moment?

Comment: I believe you should single quotes after "href="...

<a id="store" href='<%# (Session["Coupon"] == "Active") ? "url1.aspx": "url2.aspx" %>'></a>

Comment: Yes, I also tried with single quotes, the thing happening is clicking on the hyperlink reloads the same page instead of redirecting to any of two pages....really puzzled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you got confused "**#**" with "**=**". Here you have done the following:-

```
<li>
<a id="store" href= "<%# (Session["Coupon"] == "Active") ? "url1.aspx": "url2.aspx" %>"></a>
</li>
```

Note that you have used "**#**" hash tag in embedded code block, It is a binding expression and usually used when you try to bind things up in html. For e.g. **<%# Eval("Name") %>**. Now here we don't need to bind thing rather write things in html so kindly use following expression:-

```
<li>
<a id="store" href= "<%= (Session["Coupon"] == "Active") ? "url1.aspx": "url2.aspx" %>"></a>
</li>
```

You just need to replace "**#**" with "**=**" that all you need to do.

For more information kindly refer this thread [Symbols Used in Embedded Code Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833278/meaning-of-the-various-symbols-in-aspx-page-of-asp-net).