# Redirect to a new page with existing querystring using HyperLink

Tags: asp.net

I am currently on a page with one querystring ItemID available, and I am creating a hyperlink that will redirect the user to a new page with the existing querystring ItemID.

I have the asp:hyperlink as below, but it is not clickable for some reason. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hylItemReport" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/ItemReport.aspx?ItemID=" + Request.QueryString["ItemID"].ToString() %>' runat="server">Training Item</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: What does it render in the href?

Comment: There is nothing at all, I did an inspect in chrome and no href is presenting.

Comment: My binding syntax is sadly rusty. If you remove the Request.QueryString part and hardcode a value say "5" does it render properly?

Comment: if I remove the request and hardcode a number to it, it is still unclickable, but the syntax looks correct to me......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that HyperLink is not in a Repeater, GridView etc you need to call DataBind() in page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I Know ;) See this as to why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833278/meaning-of-the-various-symbols-in-aspx-page-of-asp-net. `<%#` is a binding expression so databind has to be called.